# Unable to convert an array of strings to a comma separated string

Tags: powershell

If i write the power shell as follow it will work:-

```
>>   $r = "test2@test.com","test1@test.com"
>>   Add-PnPListItem -List "title" -Values @{ "Title"  = "123";
>>  "assi" = $r}

Id    Title                                              GUID
--    -----                                              ----
7     123                                                f5687010-3f8a-4dc9-848b-8c784c1af97e
```

but if i convert an array of strings to a single string it will not work, as follow:-

```
>>  $HRCollabs.Add("""test1@test.com""")

>>  $HRCollabs.Add("""test2@test.com""")

>>  $HRCollabs
"test1@test.com"
"test2@test.com"

>> $r = $HRCollabs -join ","
>> Add-PnPListItem -List "title" -Values @{ "Title"  = "one";
>> "assi" = $r}
Add-PnPListItem : The specified user "test2@test.com","test1@test.com" could not
be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPListItem -List "title" -Values @{ "Title"  = "one";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-PnPListItem], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.AddListItem
```

Comment: Looking at the doc for this function in [Example 3](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPListItem.html#example-3) it seems that you're supposed to pass in the array itself not a multiline string. `assi` as Key doesn't seem to be documented tho. Why not just try passing the array of emails? Note that `'$r'` with the single quotes is read as a literal string not an array

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon  `assi` is a custom field inside my sharepoint

Comment: I have no experience with the function but the error leads me to believe that there is validation on this field and has no idea how to interpret multiple emails joined by a comma. If using an array works for multiple emails I believe you shouldn't touch it :P

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no i can not pass the array itself i will get user could not be found

Comment: But you're doing that on your first snippet and seems to work isn't it? If actually that doesn't work probably you need to loop over each email and call the function for each item (email)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon here `>>   $r = "test2@test.com","test1@test.com"
` i am building a stirng and not an array

Comment: That's an array in powershell not a string :P a string would be `$r = '"test2@test.com","test1@test.com"'` (note the single quotes)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes you are correct

Comment: tried piping $hrcollabs to ConverTo-Csv?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = @('a', 'b', 'c')
$string = $array -join ','
$string
```

The join operator joins a set of objects using the right hand operand as a separator.  An array is one way of providing a set.